# Issues pushing data from one array to another

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been struggling with this bit of code for a while. I'm trying to loop through an array (created from Google Spreadsheet data) and conditionally copy an entire row of data (based off the contents of one cell in that row) into a new array of rows with the same column count. I then plan on writing this array to a matching range in the spreadsheet.

The data array appears to be working correctly with `[k]` as row index and `[u]` as column index.

Currently I see this error when I run: TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined @ this line of code: targetArray[m][u].push(data[k][u]);

When i step through this line of code: targetArray[m][u].push(data[k][u]) the values are m=0, u=0, k=2, i=5. So, why can't the array element at data[5][0] be written to targetArray[0][0]? If that particular cell is empty then it should still be copied into the array, right? I'm not sure where the "undefined" is coming from. Target array is set as [] from the initialization. A sample data array element is: ["", "", "Display", "", 1, "A", "", "", ""] -> 1 row and 9 columns.

Any pointers?

```js
var sheetArray = ss.getSheets(); //returns an array of all the sheets
var numSheets = sheetArray.length;
var targetArray = [];
var m = 0; //target array counter

for (j = 6; j < numSheets; j++) {

  var data = sheetArray[j].getDataRange().getValues(); //getdatarange -> return the range of the data for the active sheet  // getvalues -> returns 2D array of values for the given range
  var numRows = data.length; //returns the number of rows in the data array
  var numColumns = data[1].length; //returns the number of columns in the 2nd row of the data array

  for (var i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) { //loop through all columns of active sheet   

    if (data[1][i] == "Build Prio [Alpha(A), Beta(B)]") { //check data heading value in each column of Row 2, when column heading matches run next for loop

      for (var k = 0; k < numRows; k++) { //k = row index & i = column index

        if (data[k][i] == 'A') { // check if cell contents are equal to A

          for (var u = 0; u < numColumns; u++) { //loop through all columns in the current row

            targetArray[m][u].push(data[k][u]); //set the value of each column in the current row to the new array                  

          }

          m++; //advances the targetArray row index                            

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use the debugger to step through each line of code and observe the content of every variable in your code.  [Google documentation - debugger and breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)  If you do that, you'll probably discover something.

Comment: Your question isn't clear - in fact, there's no question at all. What is wrong? What do you _expect to see_, and what _do you see_? We can point out a number of possible optimizations, but without a clear statement of how your code isn't meeting your expectations, there's no problem to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added some comments in the code. Don't do m++ ánd push() in the array :)

```
var sheetArray = ss.getSheets(); //returns an array of all the sheets
var numSheets = sheetArray.length;
var targetArray = [];
var m = 0; //target array counter

for (j = 6; j < numSheets; j++) {

  var data = sheetArray[j].getDataRange().getValues(); //getdatarange -> return the range of the data for the active sheet  // getvalues -> returns 2D array of values for the given range
  var numRows = data.length; //returns the number of rows in the data array
  var numColumns = data[1].length; //returns the number of columns in the 2nd row of the data array

  for (var i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) { //loop through all columns of active sheet   

    if (data[1][i] == "Build Prio [Alpha(A), Beta(B)]") { //check data heading value in each column of Row 2, when column heading matches run next for loop

      for (var k = 0; k < numRows; k++) { //k = row index & i = column index

        if (data[k][i] == 'A') { // check if cell contents are equal to A

           //just push the whole row at once:
          targetArray.push(data[k]); //push the whole row in targetarray            

          }
          //no need for m++ since push adds a row.

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```